# clang failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have downloaded a sample code of OpenEars form the web, in that at a place these statements were using:

@autoreleasepool {
    …
}
which was giving error: Unexpected '@' in program, then I replaced these lines of code with:
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
…
[pool drain];
and now I am getting error: "clang failed with exit code 1 error".

Does any one know how to solve this?
I am using XCode 3.2.5

Comment: Is the project set to use ARC?

Comment: OpenEars developer here. I missed this at the time it was posted, but for anyone reading it later with a similar problem, the issue here as 8BitAce suspected is that the OpenEars sample app uses ARC and if you want to run it without an ARC-compatible compiler, it needs to be converted to a memory-managed project.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to go back to `@autoreleasepool{}` but it sounds like the issue is in the compiler/arguments though. That may be difficult to debug, depending on how old the project was. Are you using the latest Xcode, and if so, can you "upgrade project settings"?